# Batch file IF statement won't parse (comparing two integer variables)

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am trying to make a small batch program which will re-start a program when it detects that it is not running, and also restart the program once a while.

Here is the part which CMD just says "The syntax of the command is incorrect" (won't parse after the first if statement). Both variables are set with the /a statement, so they should both be proper integers.

```
IF %delayer% GTR %resetDelay% (

IF NOT %resetDelay% EQU 0 (
  CALL :RESETMINER
  ECHO [%TIME%] %minerProcess% - scheduled restart completed.
  SET /a delayer=0
) ELSE (
  TIMEOUT %checkDelay%
)

) ELSE (

SET /a delayer=%delayer%+%checkDelay%
TIMEOUT %checkDelay% /nobreak
::Delete /nobreak if you want to skip the 'Wait' sequences by pressing any key

)
```

Here is the whole code //Removed, not important

Comment: I haven't read your 'whole code' but I would suggest using the following in your snippet instead: `IF %resetDelay% NEQ 0 (` or `IF NOT %resetDelay% == 0 (` and `SET /a delayer+=checkDelay` or `SET /a delayer=delayer+checkDelay`.

Comment: In the `if /?` shows that `NOT` is not part of that compare-op syntax.

Comment: @ACatInLove, I can't follow you, but in the above code snippet, `not` is is used perfectly fine...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `::-comments` within a code-block (parenthesised sequence of lines) as it causes problems. Change it to `rem comment`.

Comment: Oh thanks a lot, that solved my problem... I didn't even thought that this could be a problem!